# UPDATE Statement Not Updating in Execute T-SQL Task

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a simple package that flows data from point A to point B - in the middle is a row count transformation that populates a variable of type `Int32`.

After the Data Flow Task, I have a simple Execute SQL Task with an update statement:

```
UPDATE  [SAP].[SAPCopyInfo]
  SET [endtime] = GETDATE(),
      [MSEGCnt] = ?
  WHERE [BegTime] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

I have mapped my variable as a parameter like so:

[image: Execute SQL Task Parameter Mapping]

When I execute the package, the Execute SQL Task (named 'Update Log') shows success:

[image: Execution Status]

The variable watch shows that `intMSEGCnt` is populated correctly:

[image: intMSEGCnt]

Yet the table doesn't update - and there are no errors in the output window:

[image: Table]

Manually executing the `UPDATE` SQL in SSMS works fine (replacing ? with the correct value), so it doesn't appear to be a permissions issue.

I've tried various iterations of the 'Data Type' for the Parameter Mapping, yet nothing works.

I've even de-parameterized the `UPDATE` statement and run it directly in the Execute SQL Task with hardcoded values and it still doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the data type in the table you are trying to update a in your task editor LONG?  That is what the variable is defined as.  So could be issue with data type mismatch.  If it does not need to be a LONG change the SSI variable to INT.

Comment: Your `BegTime` includes a non-midnight time of day. It will never be equal to a result of `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`, so your `UPDATE` successfully updates zero rows.

Comment: Since your `BegTime` is a date/time value (not just a date), you need to provide a date/time range in your where clause - something like `WHERE BegTime >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND BegTime < DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))`. An alternative is to cast both to date like `WHERE CAST(BegTime AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`, but this is a bad habit to get into, since it prevents the efficient use of indexes to identify the matching rows to be updated.

Comment: It seems like you are inserting or creating with `GETDATE()` in an earlier step and want to then target the same row for your `UPDATE`.  But the value of `GETDATE()` will have changed by the time you get to this step.  Can you instead make a variable with the current date at the start (perhaps even the [system start time variable?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-variables?view=sql-server-ver16) ) and use that for the insert and update both?

Comment: @TN `WHERE CAST(BegTime AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` is [perfectly sargable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/5203).

Comment: @stevev `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` is accurate to the day.

Comment: @GSerg - I stand corrected. Yes the simpler for will do. *(Now I'm going to look into all the various DATE_TRUNC() options to see if the same holds true there.)*

Comment: What happens if this runs twice on the same day?

Comment: *@GSerg - Just a follow-up note: It appears that `CAST(column AS DATE) = @CompareDate` is sargable, but the equivalent `DATETRUNC(day, column) = @CompareDate` is not.  Other forms of DATETRUNC(), YEAR(), EOMONTH(), and  DATE_BUCKET() that perform similar truncate-like functions are also not optimized to use indexes, even though they potentially could be. So, it looks like we can use the simple form for day matching, but need ranges (half-open intervals) for year, fiscal-year, quarter, month, week, hour, minute, or second comparisons.*  See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-TxBXccv).*

Comment: @GSerg Not *perfectly* just mostly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you just need another set of eyes - thanks to @GSerg & @T N

The answer was to simply change the `UPDATE` query to this:

```
UPDATE  [SAP].[SAPCopyInfo]
  SET [endtime] = GETDATE(),
      [MSEGCnt] = ?
  WHERE CAST([BegTime] AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Comment: `WHERE CAST([BegTime] AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` is a bad idea as it won't utilize the index and statistics correctly. Use a date range instead `WHERE BegTime >= CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime) AND BegTime < DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)`

Comment: While I understand what you're saying, this table only contains a single row for each day and there is no performance impact.

Comment: @Charlieface While what you say is true for all the other "hiding" column within a function, in this particulare case the index will be used correctly and the statistics also, cast or convert from datetime to date is optimized in SQL Server, try it on any datetime column that has an index

Comment: @sepupic It uses a dynamic seek, and the estimates can be off as well as the predicate being out by a day, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34052/220697

Comment: @Charlieface Maybe you should read also the second answer as for 2014 and above it's not a problem and the plans for OP where clause and for suggested by you are identical

Comment: @sepupic That just helps for the statistics estimates, not for the extra day in the predicate.

Comment: @Charlieface I'm on the 2019 and I assure you I see the same estimation in both plans, if it was my question I could attach my plans here to make you see, but it is problematic to do it within the comment

Comment: @Charlieface Maybe this way: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ_E7V9np